# What are the best archers followers?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I'm having a hard time finding a list containing followers who are high skilled in archery. I need a bunch of them to experiment a team of archers following me. In case anyone's wondering I'm using a mod to get up to 10 followers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [spreadsheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aly8njaU3H1adGJYTlJaUnRxRUN2RnM5MkxPaU1mQkE#gid=0) was placed in [an article from UESP wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers#Follower_Stats) giving the values for followers aptitudes, or maximum level in the specific skill of archery:

**Max Level 100**

- Jenassa, Aela

**Max Level 98**

- Lydia, Argis, Calder, Iona, Jordis, Vilkas

**Max Level 97**

- Cicero

**Others**

- 87: Faendal
- 78: Derkeethus, Annekke, Ghorbash
- 73: Erik, Vostag, Stenvar, Mjoll
- 72: Kharjo, Ahtar
- 57: Cosnach, Golldir, Uthgerd, Benor, Borgakh, Ogol
- 50: Athis, Ria, Torvar
- 32: Roggi, Sven
- 20: J'zargo
- ??: Onmund, Erandur, Brelyna, Aranea, Illia, Eola, Marcurio, Berland, Njada, Farkas